# Smartface objects

Tags: javascript, smartface.io

I'm just starting to explore Smartface - could you please clarify how can I change property of few objects inside "for" cylcle?

I have few oblects:

```
Pages.Page.MainPage.TextButton1,
Pages.Page.MainPage.TextButton2,
Pages.Page.MainPage.TextButton3 etc
```

I have to change a property "text" of these objects:

```
Pages.Page.MainPage.TextButtonN.text = captions[i];
```

where N is integer from 1 to 10.

How can I do it?

Thank you and sorry for the dummy question. )

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic objects. I made an example that creates 5 different TextButton objects inside a for loop. 
You can use the below code to see how it works on device:

```
var i = 0, N = 5, myTop = 100, temp = "button";
var createButtons = new SMF.UI.TextButton({
        top : "80%",
        width : "100%",
        height : "10%",
        left : "0%",
        text : "create buttons",
        onPressed : function (e) {
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                var myObjectName = temp + i;
                var myObjectName = new SMF.UI.TextButton();
                myObjectName.name = temp + i;
                myObjectName.top = myTop;
                myObjectName.text = temp + i;
                myObjectName.onPressed = function (e) {
                    // some actions
                }
                Pages.Page1.add(myObjectName);
                myTop = myTop + 80;
            }
        }
    });
    Pages.Page1.add(createButtons);
```

Comment: Yep, I did it, but it seems that creating objects dynamically take a lot of time. It will be great if I could create objects once on startup application, but I'm not sure how. 

now I'm creating objects on OnShow event - it runs every time on show the page and takes about 5 seconds for 30 objects.